# flat split string with Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, java-8

How following string can be mapped to Map

**input:** Garagen/Stellplätze/Other 1/2/1

**output:**
Map =>

```
Garagen->1
Stellplätze->2
Other->1
```

any ideas?

I tried

```
Pattern.compile("\\s* \\s*") //split by space
    .splitAsStream(responseString.trim())
    .map(s -> s.split("/", 2))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a.length>1? a[1]: ""));
```

but it's get different output

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: you can use split method.

Comment: Instead of `"\\s* \\s*"`, you probably want to use `"\\s+"`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split on the whitespace. Then you have separated the keys and values. Then split by the delimiter `/`. After that setup a map and collect:

```
String input = ...
String[] data = input.split(" ");
String[] keys = data[0].split("/");
String[] values = data[1].split("/");

Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    map.put(keys[i], Integer.valueOf(values[i]));
}
```

Using the Stream API here will probably be quite hard and unreadable. The problem is that the values come after the keys and it's not that easy to interleave the sub-streams. So you will have a hard time combining the keys with their corresponding values.

Your current approach has exactly this problem:

```
Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))   // Stream<String>
    .map(data -> data.split("/")) // Stream<String[]> : [keys, values]
    ... // How to group keys[i] with values[i]?
```

I'm sure you *can* get this to work somehow. But it wouldn't be straightforward and probably confuse readers. I would just stick with regular loops. The Stream API doesn't help in every situation.

Comment: Actually you can do something using `IntRange(0,n) ` where n is the length of keys an values (so they are equal.

Comment: I was looking for Streaming solution but still its a valid point! Thanks